# Why does '?' operator use From instead of Into?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

Suppose there is an external module (provided by a third-party library):

```rust
pub mod external_module {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct ExternalError;

    pub trait SomeTrait {
        fn do_stuff(&self) -> Result<i32, ExternalError>;
    }
}
```

I need to implent `SomeTrait` in my code. There are some internal errors that my code could face, so I define my own error type and make it convertible into `ExternalError`:

```rust
struct MyError;

impl Into<ExternalError> for MyError {
    fn into(self) -> external_module::ExternalError {
        ExternalError {}
    }
}
```

Notice that I can not implement `from<MyError> for ExternalError` because `ExternalError` is defined outside of my namespace (in reality even outside of my crate).

Now I implement `SomeTrait`:

```rust
fn do_my_things() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    Ok(())
}

struct MyStruct;

impl SomeTrait for MyStruct {
    fn do_stuff(&self) -> Result<i32, ExternalError> {
        do_my_things()?;
        Ok(200)
    }
}
```

[Full code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18c7f0e73c690e55c5117197cc477f47). However, this won't compile:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `external_module::ExternalError`
  --> src/main.rs:28:23
   |
28 |         do_my_things()?;
   |                       ^ the trait `std::convert::From<MyError>` is not implemented for `external_module::ExternalError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

To make it compile, I can explicitly use `into()`:

```rust
    do_my_things().map_err(|e| e.into())?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3d71dc91700890e02f2eda9119227966). Two questions here:

1. Why does '?' operator use `From` instead of `Into`? The latter seems much more reasonable because it would be more permissive: `From<A> for B` implies `Into<B> for A`, but not the other way around.
2. What is the best way to handle error conversion in my particular case? Writing `.map_err(|e| e.into())` looks unreasonably verbose (sometimes I even have to explicitly specify types in the closure because the compiler can not deduce them!)

Some context: I was playing with [tonic](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic) when I got into this situation. The library generates traits from `.proto` files and then expects you to implement them (see [the basic helloworld](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/src/helloworld/server.rs)). In case of failure you need to return `Err(tonic::Status)`, which basically contains a GRPC error code and an error message. I don't want my inner error type to have anything to do with GRPC error codes, I only want to add them when my error gets converted into `tonic::Status`.

Comment: Interestingly, the [RFC did use `Into`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0243-trait-based-exception-handling.md#definition-of-constructs), but had [a section on whether the right trait to use was `From`, `Into` or something else](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0243-trait-based-exception-handling.md#semantics-for-upcasting). I can't find any reference to where this issue was solved, but the [initial implementation ended-up using `From`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/31954/files#diff-645fefb36415d1b63ac301829ab54fc8R1617).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `is_ok!` macro was [initally implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/ece8a8f520697be50cbe543bebe065c5198dae4d#diff-f7ad4a5ae3364771b775302f47d00063R201-R204) without implicitly error conversion. That macro was [renamed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/7bb498bd7a09f024fe46fc58ea17fe44cbc68df0#diff-f7ad4a5ae3364771b775302f47d00063L358-R358) to `try!`, and when error conversion was later [implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/6815c2e8e8dae3d8dedfe95e985a79c57841bdb2#diff-f7ad4a5ae3364771b775302f47d00063R324), they chose to use the `FromError` trait, which [later](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/e17f4fc1d4545f5c17b21805c5145b05495484ee#diff-f7ad4a5ae3364771b775302f47d00063L100-R100) was replaced with the `From<E>` trait after the more generic conversion traits were [implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/8389253df0431e58bfe0a8e0e3949d58ebe7400f#diff-da707dc4d90c85e7074dbdecebfe8785R42-R45) around 6 months later.

As @mcarton mentioned, [the RFC for the `?` operator](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0243-trait-based-exception-handling.md) used the `Into` trait for error conversion. It also says that "*The postfix `?` operator can be applied to `Result` values and is equivalent to the current `try!()` macro.*" However, as noted in [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31436#issuecomment-299638299) by stbuehler:

> Sadly there would be a regression. If no (non-trivial) `From<...>` instance for an error type is implemented, the compiler can deduce the type in certain cases, where it cannot deduce it when using `Into` (the set of `From` instances is limited by the current crate, the full set of Into instances is not known while compiling a crate).

So my interpretation of this is that the `try!` macro added error conversion support before the `From`and `Into` traits existed, and because the `?` operator should behave the same as the `try!` macro, and that changing to `Into` would break type deduction, the `?` operator was implemented using `From` instead.

---

That being said, you're allowed to implement `From<MyType> for ForeignType`, as long as `MyType` is a type in your crate:

```
struct MyError;

impl From<MyError> for ExternalError {
    fn from(err: MyError) -> external_module::ExternalError {
        ExternalError {}
    }
}
```

[Example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3aa7a107d7b59e68697f100225669bf)

Comment: Wow, I thought Rust disallows implementing external traits on external types. Is From a "special case" to this rule or there is something I am missing?

Comment: @kreo I'm not actually sure _why_ it works, I think the general rule is still that you're not allowed to do that (for instance `impl<T> From<MyType<T>> for ForeignType<T>` won't work) but sometimes it seems to be allowed nonetheless. Does not seem to be special to `From` though, as you can do the same with e.g. `AsRef`.